# Nunit testing for different environment variable values

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, .net-core, nunit

I have a nunit test project. I want to cover the condition which is based on environment values , i have written tests for that which runs pefectly when i run them individually, but it fails when I run all the tests at once, as I am changing the environment variables values according to the tests. How can I cover the code in this situation? I tried using setup and teardown methods but still same issue.

Comment: You can use the .runsettings file to specify environment variables for your test project. This way you avoid changing environment variables manually or programmatically in your test code.
You can then select the .runsettings file in Visual Studio by selecting Test > Configure Run Settings > Select Solution-Wide Run Settings File. This will apply the environment variables to your test project.

Answer (score 3):

Do not access the environment variables directly. Instead, write a service wrapping them by implementing an interface and inject it into your business logic.

```cs
public interface IEnvironment
{
     public string CurrentDirectory { get; }
     public string WindowsDirectory { get; }
}
```

Real-world implementation:

```cs
public class EnvironmentAccess : IEnvironment
{
     public string CurrentDirectory => Environment.CurrentDirectory;
     public string WindowsDirectory => Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir");
}
```

Now, you can mock this interface in unit tests. I am not using NUnit myself, but according to the docs you could do something like this:

```cs
var mock = new Mock<IEnvironment>();
mock.Setup(p => p.CurrentDirectory).Returns(@"C:\MyTestDir");
mock.Setup(p => p.WindowsDirectory).Returns(@"C:\MyTestWindows");
var env = mock.Object;
var sut = new MyClassToBeTested(env);
...
```